# How to build projects to a common directory in a Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, build

I have C# and C++ projects in Visual Studio's solution.
How to make them build into one common folder?

In C++ projects Output Directory is set to `$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`:
[image]

But in C# projects it just says `bin\release\`:
[image]

And outputs into `$(ProjectDir)bin\release` as it usually does in C# projects.

When in C# projects I set Output path to `$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`:
[image]

It creates folder named $(SolutionDir)$(Platform) inside its project folder: [image]

I would like files from all of my projects to be output to `$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`. So on a Debug x86 Build configuration it will be `$(SolutionDir)bin\x86\Debug` and on a Release x64 Configuration build it will be `$(SolutionDir)bin\x64\Release`.

I googled it and searched it here on Stackoverflow but I can't find a solution.

The closest thing I found is to use Build Events in C# projects and set output to `$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`.
But the problem with this approach is that in C# projects the Platform is always set to `Any CPU`:
[image]

And appropriate target platform is set in another field called `Target platform`:
[image]